# Arduino Uno "WiFi Developer Edition" - How to disable WiFi?

Tags: communication, avrdude, arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

I'm using Arduino Uno "Wifi Developer Edition". I made my Arduino to get connected with my local network based on http://www.arduino.org/learning/getting-started/getting-started-with-arduino-uno-wifi

Now I would like to disable it and work with USB serial communication to upload sketches. But now I'm unable to upload sketches even if I select the serial port. I'm getting an AVRDUDE : seropen() Access is disabled error. I could perfectly do uploading if I select the networked port of the same Arduino.

Can I know why ?

Comment: The serial should work regardless of the network. You could check the webinterface, but the problem seems to be on the serial side. Though I've never worked with the Arduino wifi

Comment: Have you installed al serial drivers and does it show in device manager? And try restarting your PC and running the Arduino IDE as administrator

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable the Wi-Fi. The serial works with the Wi-Fi enabled.
You need to first install the driver and then select the Serial port on the Arduino IDE.

Comment: did you ever work with Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why "Arduino WiFi Dev Ed" USB upload sometimes doesn't work, is the esp8266 connected to UART of Atmega for the OTA upload. If esp8266 doesn't boot, it doesn't set pin 4 to disconnect from Atmega UART and the connection to UART stays and disturbs the upload from IDE.

The esp8266 hangs sometimes, because it has pin 2 floating on this board, but there is a trace and a soldering point on the bottom of the board for pin 2. If it is touched or otherwise grounded the esp8266 doesn't boot until the potential on the pin rises.

More about Uno WiFi Dev Ed hardware [here](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/wiki/Hardware).